# How to use touch events without importing a whole mobile-driven JavaScript framework?

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, touch

I'm working on a responsive design on which I'd like to use two specific touch events, `tap` and `swipe`. Is it possible to import a single jQuery Mobile slice (i.e. [jquery.mobile.events.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.event.js)) or a piece of any other mobile-driven JavaScript framework, without importing the entire set of assets? I'm currently using jQuery, just so you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem: [TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html), a jQuery plugin for touch devices that handles swipe events. Like a boss!

Comment: Were you able to successfully use TouchSwipe and the jQuery Mobile framework?  TouchSwipe seems to stop working after I add the jQuery Mobile framework/js file to the page.

Answer (score 12):

You can also just download the module **Events.Touch** from jQuery Mobile using their download builder
http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Just tick the option 'Touch', add the JavaScript file to your project so you can start listening to events such as:

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend
- tap
- taphold
- swipe
- swipeleft
- swiperight
- scrollstart
- scrollstop

ps: You must be using the jQuery library as jQuery mobile runs on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TouchSwipe Jquery plugin, it is the easiest plugin ever when Jquery performed.

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

```
$(function() {
  $(".carousel-inner").swipe({
    allowPageScroll:"auto",
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      if(direction == 'left'){
        $(this).parent().carousel('prev');
      }
      else if(direction == 'right') {
        $(this).parent().carousel('next');
      }
    }
  });
});
```